# MongoDB - Count value occurrences for field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

**Document structure**

```
{
"A": "1",
"B": "3",
"C": "0.000090213",
},
{
"A": "1",
"B": "3",
"C": "0.000037698",
},
{
"A": "2",
"B": "4",
"C": "0.00016664",
}
```

I'm trying to get the count of value for specific fields with aggregation, desired result for A and B would be

```
A: { "1": 2, "2": 1}
B: { "3": 2, "4": 1}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to solve my issue with:

`db.collection.aggregate([ {$group: { _id: { name: "A"}, count: { $sum: 1 }}},{$sort: { _id: 1 }  },{$group: { _id: "$_id.name", count: { $sum: "$count" }, } },{ $sort: { _id: 1 }},])`

Do you have a clue how would one solve this using $inc?

Comment: Forgot to type a $ sign in front of A in the first group.

Comment: _"Do you have a clue how would one solve this using $inc"_ - [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) is an Update Operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $facet: {
  "A": [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$A",
        v: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
   ],
  "B": [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$B",
        v: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
     }
   ]
  }
  },
  {
   $addFields: {
   A: {
    $map: {
      input: "$A",
      as: "a",
      in: {
        k: "$$a._id",
        v: "$$a.v"
      }
     }
    }
  }
 },
 {
   $addFields: {
     B: {
      $map: {
      input: "$B",
      as: "b",
      in: {
        k: "$$b._id",
        v: "$$b.v"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
 {
   $project: {
    A: {
       "$arrayToObject": "$A"
       },
    B: {
    "$arrayToObject": "$B"
       }
      }
     }
   ])
```

Explained:

1. $group the desired keys in two separate pipes with $facet
2. $addFields to rename _id to k ( suitable for $arrayToObject )
3. $project the desired counts with $arrayToObject.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2lpxVrKrvxz)